# Why has my question been closed as "Opinion Based"?

Tags: discussion

Why has [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12469/names-of-the-electromagnetic-units-in-si) been closed as “opinion based”? What did I put in the question that is making it an opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post was voted-to-close by five members of our community. I cannot speak for them, and won't try to reconstruct their reasoning. However, I think that your question is comparable to some other questions which have been allowed on this site, so I will not do any great harm by reopening it.

In the future, perhaps try to pose your questions in a more focused manner, getting straight to the point and asking a single, precise question. This usually helps a lot!